# try-except with files handle (where to close)

Tags: python, try-catch

Suppose I want to introduce a try-except block while handling a txt file. Which of the two following way of capturing the possible exception is correct?

```
try:
    h = open(filename)
except:
    h.close()
    print('Could not read file')



try:
    h = open(filename)
except:
  
    print('Could not read file')
```

In other words, should the h.close() be called even if the exception occurs or not?

Secondly, suppose that you have the following code

```
try:
    h = open(filename)
    "code line here1"
    "code line here2"
except:
    h.close()
    print('Could not read file')
```

If an error occurs in "code line here1", should I use h.close() in the except block?

Is there a difference with the previous coding lines?

Comment: The best way to do it is to open the file with `with open(filename) as h:`. Then it will be closed automatically when the program flow leaves the `with` block. And you should never use an empty `except`. Specify which exception you want to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `with`, it will close the file appropriately:

```
with open(filename) as h:
    #
    # do whatever you need...
    # 
# when you get here, the file will be closed automatically.
```

You can enclose that in a try/except block if needed. The file will always be properly closed:

```
try:
    with open(filename) as h:
        #
        # do whatever you need...
        #
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('file not found')
```